# Correct way to build a basic filter bank (ie. for simple multiband audio processing)?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

I need to build a filter bank for multiband processing. Last time I tried I was just starting at coding/DSP so I failed and didn't get a flat spectrum out of it. I just want to know the basic principle before I try again.

My understanding is you just need a series of high/low pass filters. The steeper the filters the more band separation you'll get.

I am guessing I would want a 12 dB/oct 2nd order design most commonly. So if I take some standard 2nd order high/low pass filters, like State Variable Filters, then I would want to set the Q to 1/sqrt(2) or 0.707 right? Because I don't want resonance.

Then I am confused as to whether I actually even need both high and low pass filters or if I'm just supposed to pick one type and build the whole thing with just that one type. ie. All low pass filters or all high pass filters.

To illustrate, let's say you wanted to split some white noise into 5 bands. You would have:

```
double whiteNoise = whiteNoiseGenerator();
SVFilter LPF1;
SVFilter LPF2;
SVFilter LPF3;
SVFilter LPF4;
SVFilter HPF1;
SVFilter HPF2;
SVFilter HPF3;
SVFilter HPF4;
float cutoffFreq1 = 250.f;
float cutoffFreq2 = 1000.f;
float cutoffFreq3 = 3000.f;
float cutoffFreq4 = 8000.f;
float filterQ = 1/sqrt(2);
```

Then you would set your filters in terms of Q and cutoff:

```
LPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq1);
HPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq1);
LPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq2);
HPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq2);
LPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq3);
HPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq3);
LPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq4);
HPF1.setFilter(filterQ, cutoffFreq4);
```

Then for processing what do you do next? Again, do you even need the HPFs? Couldn't you just subtract the prior filtered result from the next one? Like:

```
whiteNoise = whiteNoiseGenerator();
double outputBand1 = LPF1.process(whiteNoise);
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand1;
double outputBand2 = LPF2.process(whiteNoise);
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand2;
double outputBand3 = LPF3.process(whiteNoise);
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand3;
double outputBand4 = LPF4.process(whiteNoise);
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand4;
double outputBand5 = whiteNoise;
```

So you start with a full spectrum of white noise, and at each interval you just low pass to take a slice of that noise out and put it into the band you want. Since you subtract it from the remaining noise at each stage, the next stage only sees what remains from the prior filtrations. You don't need any HPF and the total amount of noise is unchanged since it all adds up so it must be flat.

I think that will work but it will create "slanted" crossovers between the bands along the axis of the LPF curves. To get straight crossovers I would need to use the HPFs too. Maybe like this:

```
whiteNoise = whiteNoiseGenerator();
double HPF1output = HPF1.process(whiteNoise);
double outputBand1 = LPF1.process(whiteNoise) - HPF1output;
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand1;
double HPF2output = HPF2.process(whiteNoise);
double outputBand2 = LPF2.process(whiteNoise) - HPF2output;
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand2;
double HPF3Output = HPF3.process(whiteNoise);
double outputBand3 = LPF3.process(whiteNoise) - HPF3output;
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand3;
double HPF4Output = HPF4.process(whiteNoise);
double outputBand4 = LPF4.process(whiteNoise) - HPF4output;
whiteNoise = whiteNoise - outputBand4;
double outputBand5 = whiteNoise;
```

Does that make sense? If so, do I set the cutoffs the same for each pair of high/low passes or do I need to stagger them somehow to keep things flat if it's say a 12 dB/oct 2nd order state variable filter?

Thanks

Comment: Hi mike, have seen DASP and DAFX books from Zölzer? Possibly giving such design recipes...

Comment: Yeah pretty sure I actually bought a DAFX electronic copy a few years ago. Can't remember where I have it or have access to it from. Anyway, I think this is a pretty simple issue and it should be easily answered if known. People build these for audio plugins for example very commonly. Multiband processing is very common.

Comment: @Fat32 I found DAFX in my Google books account but no help.